# How to increase a space to fit an ad on Wix?

Tags: wix

I am building a website which I'd like to use specifically for ad revenue and I would like to increase the space which is marked with the red arrows or equivalently to reduce the image. How do I do this?

[image]

Comment: Most of our regulars don't use Wix and don't recommend Wix because of their vendor-lock-in policies.  You may not get an answer here quickly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I'm not that good of a programmer so I'm building my website on Wix. What other platform would you recommend for a person like me?

Comment: The most popular content management system (CMS) is WordPress from https://wordpress.org/   I usually suggest finding a Wordpress host (but I don't suggest using wordpress.com.)

Comment: Standard Wix has strict horizontal boundaries because it only supports Desktop and Mobile. It does not use breakpoints, which you will need to properly implement this. Editor-X _does_ but even then I don't think this is a good idea. I do not think either Editor-X or Wix can handle programmatic ads. I would use Wordpress with a page builder theme like Divi...or the other one I can't remember the name of. I'm sure there are some guides for setting up ads.

Comment: And even with a WordPress page builder, the site is still going to be insanely bloated. I would not be surprised if for some users it takes 3-5 seconds for the ad to show up _after_ the page has been loaded.

Comment: @MikeCiffone so how do I build a website which would not be slow? Do it myself from scratch with JS/CSS?